# Corrupt Database

Tags: sql-server, corruption

I am Looking For Best Way or Software To Recover Corrupt Database in SQL 2000/2005/2008 . looking for Ur help .......................................

Comment: Not a programming question - nudging over to SU.

Comment: Backup and recovery is an Admin issue - should be on Server Fault.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a backup and if it is in suspect mode:

- Set your database into emergency
  mode, then single_user mode.
- Run DBCC checkdb with
  repair_allow_data_loss
- Set to multi_user mode and try to
  recover your data. Of course, some
  data might have been lost during 
  repair.

Comment: You forgot 4th point: look for a new job ;)

Answer (score 2):

Dont do it. Point. it is corrupte - if this is only indices (DBCC tells you), drop and recreat ethem. If not - the corrupt data is lost.

Take your backup, apply it. Then apply the transaction logs since last backup. Finished.

If you have no backup, look for another job.

Answer (score 0):

Don't take our advice.  Read some articles written by Paul Randal, who wrote the DBCC CHECK utilities for sql server.

[Corruption Recovery Tips, Database Shrinkage Advice and More](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee914612.aspx)

[Paul's DBCC CHECKDB blog series on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/tags/DBCC+CHECKDB+Series/default.aspx)

[Paul's Blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/CHECKDB-From-Every-Angle.aspx)

It would also help if you described the corruption problem your having with some specific error messages your getting from SQL Server.